# using host headers with sharepoint

Tags: web-application, host-header

I need to make a development machine, so I have made a web application on port 80, gave it host header: google.sharepoint.com, I just wanted to play with names and see how it will be, so I added a host name in DNS, for google, and IP of my server, and in the binding in IIS I changed the binding for the web application to google.sharepoint.com, but now when I go to my site collection on http://google.sharepoint.com, it sends me to sharepoint.com.

Is it possible to use such names in development? or I can't use well known names for my sites?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a zone named "Sharepoint.com" on your DNS server(s), so they become authoratiative (to you) for the sharepoint.com zone.  Otherwise, your DNS servers are going to identify the actual authoratitive DNS servers for sharepoint.com (on the public Internet).

Alternatively, you can edit your local machine's hosts file for 'google.sharepoint.com' and point it to the IP of your developer server.

Comment: Can you provide me with the steps to do so on the DNS? Also, will it be different if I use another name for that? If I use something like: Machine.dev.com, will it work without changing DNS?

Comment: A better approach is to use a different TLD than ".com" as that actually resolves to a valid domain.  Use ".local" or ".dev" instead.  You still have to configure DNS/hosts to get the request there though...

Comment: I would generally suggest purchasing a domain instead.  Given .com domains are ~$7/year, it provides a more 'real' environment to work with.